# Can someone help me to Fitting table Beamer LaTeX

Tags: tables, beamer

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\framesubtitle{}
\begin{itemize} 
    \item Son preference and female participation in decisionmaking (parity wise) 
\end{itemize}
Table 1: Partial results (probit estimation)
\scriptsize
\small
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{10}{d{2.5}r} }
        \toprule
        Variables & \multicolumn{20}{c}{Decisions} \\
        \cmidrule(l){2-21}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Healthcare}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Social}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Consumption} 
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Financial} 
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{All} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-13} 
        \cmidrule(lr){14-17} \cmidrule(l){18-21}  
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}\\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{18}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\emph{Sons} (ref: none)}  \\
        At least one son
        & 0.156^{***} & (0.059) & 0.088 & (0.228) 
        & 0.224^{***} & (0.063) & 0.057 & (0.240) 
        & 0.168^{***} & (0.064) & 0.134 & (0.152) 
        & 0.020       & (0.068) & 0.175 & (0.214) 
        & 0.226^{***} & (0.076) & 0.205 & (0.238) \\

        Marginal effect
        & 0.053^{***} & (0.020) & 0.031 & (0.081) 
        & 0.073^{***} & (0.020) & 0.019 & (0.082) 
        & 0.054^{***} & (0.020) & 0.046 & (0.053) 
        & 0.007       & (0.024) & 0.063 & (0.078) 
        & 0.064^{***} & (0.022) & 0.059 & (0.072) \\
        Constant
        & -1.579^{***} & (0.201) & -0.696^{**}  & (0.309) 
        & -1.657^{***} & (0.194) & -0.907^{***} & (0.307) 
        & -1.634^{***} & (0.208) & -0.856^{***} & (0.282) 
        & -0.498^{**}  & (0.228) & -0.283       & (0.323) 
        & -0.291       & (0.209) &  0.012       & (0.374) \\) \
        Controls
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes }
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes }
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes }
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes } \\

        Observations
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4906} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5111}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4909} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5126}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4908} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5118}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3789} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4743}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3778} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4719} \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \footnotesize{\textcolor{black}{Source: Authors' calculations. Standard errors in parentheses . Significance level: *** p\textless 0.01, ** p\textless0.05, * p\textless0.1}}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: In particular, I am unfamiliar with the `d` column type.

Answer (score 1):

This solution places the table in a separate document which can be viewed independently.  Click the unreadable table to see the separate document.  To return to the slides, close the window containing the table.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Results}
\framesubtitle{}
\begin{itemize} 
    \item Son preference and female participation in decisionmaking (parity wise) 
\end{itemize}
Table 1: Partial results (probit estimation)

\href[pdfnewwindow,pdfremotestartview=FitV]{test5.pdf}%
  {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{test5.pdf}}%

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Where `test5.pdf` was generated using

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l *{10}{Sr} }
        \toprule
        Variables & \multicolumn{20}{c}{Decisions} \\
        \cmidrule(l){2-21}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Healthcare}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Social}
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Consumption} 
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Financial} 
        & \multicolumn{4}{c}{All} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-13} 
        \cmidrule(lr){14-17} \cmidrule(l){18-21}  
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} \le3$)}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{($\text{Parity} >3$)}\\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{18}{p{0.7\textwidth}}{\emph{Sons} (ref: none)}  \\
        At least one son
        & 0.156\textsuperscript{***} & (0.059) & 0.088 & (0.228) 
        & 0.224\textsuperscript{***} & (0.063) & 0.057 & (0.240) 
        & 0.168\textsuperscript{***} & (0.064) & 0.134 & (0.152) 
        & 0.020       & (0.068) & 0.175 & (0.214) 
        & 0.226\textsuperscript{***} & (0.076) & 0.205 & (0.238) \\

        Marginal effect
        & 0.053\textsuperscript{***} & (0.020) & 0.031 & (0.081) 
        & 0.073\textsuperscript{***} & (0.020) & 0.019 & (0.082) 
        & 0.054\textsuperscript{***} & (0.020) & 0.046 & (0.053) 
        & 0.007       & (0.024) & 0.063 & (0.078) 
        & 0.064\textsuperscript{***} & (0.022) & 0.059 & (0.072) \\
        Constant
        & -1.579\textsuperscript{***} & (0.201) & -0.696\textsuperscript{**}  & (0.309) 
        & -1.657\textsuperscript{***} & (0.194) & -0.907\textsuperscript{***} & (0.307) 
        & -1.634\textsuperscript{***} & (0.208) & -0.856\textsuperscript{***} & (0.282) 
        & -0.498\textsuperscript{**}  & (0.228) & -0.283       & (0.323) 
        & -0.291       & (0.209) &  0.012       & (0.374) \\
        Controls
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Yes} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes }
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes }
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes }
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ Yes } \\

        Observations
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4906} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5111}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4909} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5126}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4908} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{5118}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3789} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4743}
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{3778} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{4719} \\
        \bottomrule
    \multicolumn{20}{l}{%
    \footnotesize\textcolor{black}{Source: Authors' calculations. Standard errors in parentheses . Significance level: *** p\textless 0.01, ** p\textless0.05, * p\textless0.1}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: slide]